# Occasional timeout problems with get() function using python multiproccessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am relatively new to python, but I have an issue that I just cannot understand.

I am trying to implement multiprocessing on piece of code that computes the mandelbrot fractal. My problem is that, it seemingly works and doesn't work at random, and I don't understand why.

I have narrowed the problem down to specifically the .get() function that i am running to get data from the "ApplyResult" multiprocessing objects. It seems that this function will time out and run forever or until it is terminated. Occasionally the code will run once or twice, and then stop working, which suggests to me some kind of ports that are being used and not released, but everything I try to add to the code to fix this doesn't seem to help.

I have tried removing the "if name = main" part, which seemingly makes no difference, I have tried other functions I could find in the multiprocessing documentation to release the ports, including,.join() .kill(), .terminate(), as well as trying without the close altogether.
The relevant part of my code looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
I = 100
T = 2
N = 100
C_rerow = np.reshape(np.linspace(-2, 1, N), (1, N))
C_imrow = np.reshape(np.linspace(1.5, -1.5, N), (N, 1))
C = C_rerow + C_imrow*1j 

def mandel(C_row):
    Mandelbrot = np.ones_like(np.absolute(C_row))
    Z_old = np.zeros_like(C[:,0])
    for i in range(I):
        Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
        Z_old = Z_new
        Bool = (np.absolute(Z_new) > T) & (Mandelbrot == 1)
    Mandelbrot[Bool] = i/I
return Mandelbrot

def MultiP(C, I, T):
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=os.cpu_count() - 1)
    Mc = []
    for j in range(N):
        C_row = C[j,:]
        test = pool.apply_async(mandel, (C_row,))
        Mc.append(test)
    pool.close()
return Mc
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Mc = MultiP(C, I, T)
    Mc = [Mc[i].get(timeout = 5) for i in range(len(Mc))]
```

Another strange issue that I can't understand is, that if I rename the output of MultiP to something different than what the function returns, (eg rename Mc = MultiP() to MC = MultiP(), then the returned values just will not be saved. I've never seen anything like that happen with functions before, and I'm not sure if the problems are related, but I thought I would mention it.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment and perhaps not quite an answer. The bottom line is that I could not reproduce your error, but I did have a few remarks.

Code that create new processes needs to be conditionally executed by the test `if __name__ == '__main__':` on those platforms that use the operating system `spawn` rather than `fork` method of creating new processes. In such cases, the new process does not inherit a copy of the main process's address space as it was when the sub-process was created but instead starts execution from the top of the program re-executing everything it finds at global scope. If it weren't for the `if __name__ == '__main__':` test, it would recursively attempt to create even more sub-processes in an endless loop. Consequently, it's a good practice not to have complex calculations done at the global scope that do not really need to be there for they will be re-executed by every sub-process in your multiprocessing pool. It is better to move those calculations to within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. If the worker functions that you will be calling need to access those values you can either pass then as function arguments (this can be costly if these are large pieces of data) or initialized once each sub-process's address space with a global variable, as is done below.

I also tried to re-create the problem you cited in renaming the return value from `MultiP` from `Mc` to `MC` but had no problems. I also corrected your indentation errors.

When you execute the sequence `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()`, you will block until all submitted tasks complete. So if you have submitted asynchronous tasks with `apply_async` and do not need to get any return values from the returned `AsyncResult` instances created, you can use `close` and `join` to be sure the tasks have finished executing. If you are using method `get` on the returned `AsyncResult` instances, you are also guaranteed that the tasks have completed (or timed out in your case), in which case there is really no need to be issuing `close` and `join`. By the way, just because you get a `TimeoutError` exception when you call `get` signifying that the task has timed out, it is still actually running. Presumably you do not want to wait for timed out tasks to complete. You should therefore call `pool.terminate()` to kill any running tasks (this is implicitly called at the termination of a `with Pool() as poll:` block.

Note the comments I have added.

Rhetorical questions for you (they don't need to be answered, but should be thought about):

1. You have global variables `C`, `I`, `T`, `N`. Function `MultiP` accepts `C`, `I` and `T` as arguments ignoring the global variables but accesses global variable `N`. `mandel` accesses everything it needs as global variables. Isn't this inconsistent?
2. `MultiP` contains the logic to repeatedly call `mandel`. It could be doing this with or without multiprocessing. With multiprocessing it could be using `apply_async` or the potentially more efficient `map` method (*if* all the arguments were put into a list and *if* you used a suitable *chunksize* argument, which turned out to be greater than 1). Yet you return back to its caller *not* the final results but rather a list of `AsyncResult` instances. This means that the caller is dependent on the implementation details of `MulitiP`. Since the caller is immediately "getting" the results anyway, wouldn't it be wiser just to have `MultiP` "get" and return the results and reduce the coupling between caller and callee?

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

N = 100
I = 100
T = 2

def init_pool(c):
    global C
    C = c

def mandel(C_row):
    Mandelbrot = np.ones_like(np.absolute(C_row))
    Z_old = np.zeros_like(C[:,0])
    for i in range(I):
        Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
        Z_old = Z_new
        Bool = (np.absolute(Z_new) > T) & (Mandelbrot == 1)
    Mandelbrot[Bool] = i/I
    return Mandelbrot

def MultiP(C, I, T):
    # initialize each sub-process's global C variable:
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=os.cpu_count() - 1, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(C,))
    Mc = []
    for j in range(N):
        C_row = C[j,:]
        test = pool.apply_async(mandel, (C_row,))
        Mc.append(test)
    # previous 5 statements can be replaced with:
    # Mc = [pool.apply_async(mandel, (C[j,:],)) for j in range(N)]
    #pool.close() # not required
    return Mc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # moved here so the calculations are done once:
    C_rerow = np.reshape(np.linspace(-2, 1, N), (1, N))
    C_imrow = np.reshape(np.linspace(1.5, -1.5, N), (N, 1))
    C = C_rerow + C_imrow*1j
    MC = MultiP(C, I, T)
    # The following can throw a TimeoutError exception:
    MC = [MC[i].get(timeout = 5) for i in range(len(MC))]
    print(MC)
```

Prints:

```
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:19: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in absolute
  Bool = (np.absolute(Z_new) > T) & (Mandelbrot == 1)
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:17: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in square
  Z_new = Z_old**2 + C_row
test.py:19: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in absolute
  Bool = (np.absolute(Z_new) > T) & (Mandelbrot == 1)
[array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]), array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]), array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,

etc.
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I asked a programmer friend to help me, and according to him the problem is windows. At first he could not replicate the errors on linux. 
Anyway, his comments were that I should try to fix the overflow errors first, since even though I am not using them they might somehow interfere in the inner workings of the OS, if that doesn't work he suggested I run a virtual linux system, and go from there. I am paraphrasing a bit here since he told me some technical details that I can't really remember. 

Thank you for the reply, and I will consider the rhetorical questions.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was running under Windows 10.